# AzureDevOps ServiceTags Availability for NSG

Tags: azure-devops

Is service tag for Azure DevOps in roadmap? if yes, do we have an ETA on the availability? or Do we have any other tags which covers Azure DevOps IP range?

As of now, we have Azure DevOps Agent IP ranges available online through weekly XML but we dont have a tag for Azure DevOps as of now to be used with NSGs.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#agent-ip-ranges

Answer (score 0):

It appears [from this issue](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217313-networking/suggestions/37667815-azure-devops-whitelisting) that Azure is not implementing a service tag, but instead thinking of creating a product where you can spin up semi-managed build agents inside your own subscription.

Details can be found on the [design in github](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/blob/master/docs/design/byos.md)

Answer (score 0):

[Azure DevOps Service Tag have been released](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/azure-devops-service-tag-released/)

> Now that a service tag has been set up for Azure DevOps Services, customers can easily allow access by adding the tag name AzureDevOps to their NSGs or firewalls programmatically using Powershell and CLI. The portal will be supported at a later date. Customers may also use the service tag for on-prem firewall via a JSON file download. Azure Service Tags are supported for inbound connection only from Azure DevOps to customers’ on-prem. Outbound connection from customers’ networks to Azure DevOps is not supported. Customers are still required to allow the Azure Front Door (AFD) IPs provided in the doc for outbound connections. The inbound connection applies to the following scenarios documented here.

Note: Service Tag AzureDevOps is available from the portal now.

[However this will not cover IP Ranges of MS Hosted agents](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/15214)